# Brown on emerging pumpkin fruit?

Tags: pumpkins

I have planted a pumpkin which has been growing really well, however today when I came up And started weeding around my plants found a brown wide ring on the emerging fruit.

Any suggestions what this might be and do I need to be worried? [image]